# Soundness and Completeness Logic

Tags: analysis, logic

I'm taking a software analysis class and was asked the following question:

[Analysis and Program Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2QNL.png)

Suppose the SHADED portion denotes all programs that do NOT contain divide-by-zero errors, and the UNSHADED portion within the black rectangle denotes all programs that DO contain such errors.

Let A1, A2, and A3 be different program analyses which check for divide-by-zero errors.  Each analysis either ACCEPTS (i.e. declares it free of divide-by-zero errors) or REJECTS (i.e. declares that at least one divide-by-zero error exists in) a given program.

For each analysis, the programs accepted by that analysis are contained INSIDE the corresponding oval, and the programs rejected by that analysis are contained OUTSIDE the corresponding oval.

With reference to Question 4, suppose we design an analysis A4 which behaves as follows on input program P:

```
if (A1 rejects P) reject P;
else if (A3 accepts P) accept P; 
else run forever;
```

Is A4 sound?  Is A4 complete?

I chose A4 was sound because A1 accepts Programs which are valid and rejects those which are not.  This was marked correct. I said it was not complete because A4 did not accept programs which were indeed valid programs and was marked wrong.  Wondering if someone could shed a little light on this for me?

Comment: Do you consider a program that just runs forever on every input a complete solution to this problem? (That's what you get if you push $A1$ and $A3$ to the extremes of all programs and no programs respectively.)

Comment: A1 and A3 are not a spanning set of all the programs. They do not include some valid programs, which is why I did not think this was "complete".  If there was a mutation in there that changed the set A1 or A3 slightly then I would believe that eventually, it would turn into a completely spanning set.

Comment: Sorry. I misread. The marker just made a mistake.